# VBA - Insert a Formula and Convert to a Value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to insert a formula into a range of cells, and then I want to convert the formula to values.

I tired using `.Value = .Value` but didn't have much luck.

This is the code I have so far -

```
With ThisWorkbook
    With .Sheets("Raw Data")
        .Range(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(0, -1)).Value.Formula = _
            "=Instructions!$D$9"
    End With
End With
```

Any suggestions on how to alter this?

Comment: So you want the result of the formula to be the value of the cell instead of the formula, is that right?

Comment: Write the `.Formula` only, not `.Value.Formula`. Then do `.Value = .Value`.

Comment: If so, set `.formula` = `.value` instead.

Comment: Or just write the value directly and skip using a formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the formula you're using is actually `"=Instructions!$D$9"`, then you can just skip using a formula and transfer the value directly.

```
With ThisWorkbook
    With .Sheets("Raw Data")
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(0, -1))
        
        rng.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Instructions").Range("D9").Value
    End With
End With
```

If that was just a sample formula and you actually need to write a formula to be calculated, then:

```
With ThisWorkbook
    With .Sheets("Raw Data")
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(0, -1))

        rng.Formula = "Yourformulahere"
        rng.Value = rng.Value
    End With
End With
```